# Array to String conversion on phpredis zScan

Tags: php, phpredis

When using a sorted set and doing a zScan call on it, I get a Notice for Array to String conversion and I do wonder where that comes from. Does anyone have an idea?

This is the code:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1');
$redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER, Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP);
$redis->zAdd('check', 0, array('a'));
$it = NULL;
$redis->zScan('check', $it);
```

Tried that with `Redis::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY` too but got the same results. It must be the value set because if I do a `$redis->zAdd('check', 0,'a');` everything is fine.

I am using PHP 7.1.12 with php-redis 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't allow array keys to be arrays.  The following script will cause an `illegal offset type` error.

```
<?php
$array = [
    ['one'] => 0,
    ['two'] => 1
];
?>
```

A few phpredis commands "zip" the responses which means the actual Redis reply of `[key, value, key, value]` is turned into the PHP like associative array `[key => value, key => value]`.

You're running into this problem with `zScan` as internally when it is attempting to zip the values, PHP is forced to use the value `"Array"` as an array key cannot be an array.

You would see the same problem if you tried to do this:

```
$redis->zRange('check', 0, -1, true);
```

I didn't step through the code but my guess is that the problem happens precisely [here](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/library.c#L1111).

I don't know anything about what you're trying to build, so it's difficult to say what a proper workaround might be.  You can always disable serialization before attempting to execute `ZSCAN` or `ZRANGE WITHSCORES` but then you'd need to deal with the serialized data manually.

Comment: I do not add an array as key but as a value. 'check' is the key. According to https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#zadd the value can only be a string. I am using hSet now which works even with arrays which are serialized before setting. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, a serialized array as the ZSET member, and if you run `zScan` on that set, phpredis attempts to return `[member => score]`.  Your member is a serialized array, so it attempts to unserialize the array and use it as an array key, which is illegal.  I wrote that part of phpredis.  Glad you got it working! :)